# Gas cost for keep the contract

Tags: contract-development, gas

In Ethereum yellowpaper the gas cost to create a contract is equal 32000. But what is the cost to validate and keep the contract operating until it is executed?

**Edit:**

Imagine the following situation: I want to transfer an amount of ether from wallet X to wallet Y. I will use a smart contract to do the validation of the transfer. By my understanding the cost would be:

32 000 gas to create a new contract;
After the contract was validated, 21000 gas would be added to the cost of the contract because the transaction would be validated.

My questions are: is this analogy correct?

Anything I do in the Ethereum blockchain can be considered a transaction? (If I just want to store a value in the blockchain (i.e. 256 bit value has a cost of 20 000 gas) I would have to pay the gas for store the value and also the gas cost of a transaction?

Comment: "I would have to pay the gas for store the value and also the gas cost of a transaction?" The cost of the transaction would include the cost of storing the bytes. (There's no cost for anything other than a transaction, but a transaction's cost can vary depending on what it does.)

Comment: Understood, so basically the total cost should be 20000(storage)+21000(transaction) = 41 000 gas. Correct?

Comment: Yes. (A bit more due to other instructions being executed, the cost of the data being sent, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, but I think the answer is 0. Gas is only paid when you make a transaction. Deploying (creating) a contract is a transaction, and then calling a function in that contract is a transaction, but in between there are no transactions and thus no gas paid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I eddited my question to better detail my doubt.